# What is the difference between modifying the alpha and the contrast?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Could someone explain what is the difference between contrast and alpha? (is there any difference...?)

when talking about OpenCV, it seems to be the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrast is the color difference which makes the objects distinguishable. Alpha, on the other hand, is the variable that indicates the transparency of a pixel.

If you want to increase the contrast, you can do this by enwidening the histogram of an image. See [`histogram equalization`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html). CLAHE will give the best results.

If you want to add transparency to an image, you can write out the 4-channel image (blue - green - red - alpha) as **.png**. If you want to blend two images, you can use [`addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) or write a function of your own.

Comment: so the alpha value in cv::convertTo (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html)   and the actual Alpha channel of an image are different things?

Comment: @21kc I see the confusion now. Alpha and beta here are just variables like x and y. They represent the gain and bias parameters, as it says. Alpha channel is a completely different thing, and not related to this topic. What it does here is that it shrinks or enwidens the original histogram by alpha, and shifts it by beta. Therefore, the operation in the link you provided does linear contrast adjustment.